# How do I find all the drastic changes in the stock and fetch news for those days of the stock?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am analyzing MindTree company's stocks as an internship project using python pandas and have been given the task to find all the drastic changes by looking at the produced plot for the stock and fetch news for those days of the stock. I am not sure what is considered a drastic change in the stock market. How do I find all the drastic changes in the stock? Also which news API should I use to find the news for those specific days? [image: Plot of MindTree stock]

Comment: I am thinking of finding the mean and then compare all the closing prices with the mean and find the difference between them and then store them in an array and then sort the array in descending order. Am I thinking straight?

Comment: i am doing the same internship,what i am thinking of doing is first taking out the difference of the column then sorting it in descending order of the absolute values.
What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it probably has a great deal to do with what you are planning on doing with the results of your model. For example, if you are looking for news that corresponds to a move of the stock price by more than 3% on that day, you would only want to look at those days. Alternatively, if you are looking for 'abnormally large' movements in the stock price, you might consider taking the mean and standard deviation of your day to day movements and only considering those days that are more than two or three standard deviations from the mean.

In terms of how to get the news for a particular day, here is a python tutorial that may be useful:
https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/basic/python-basic-1-exercise-8.php